# How to see Log Outputs of Azure Data Factory Custom Activity

Tags: .net-core, azure-data-factory

I have a custom activity implemented in Dotnet in a Azure Data Factory pipeline and I want to see the console outputs. How can I read these outputs to debug my pipeline? Some predefined activities have the possibility to export the logs to a storage account but this checkbox does not exist for custom activities.

Below is my activities code using `Console.WriteLine` which I would like to check in a log.

```cs
 private static void DeleteBlobFiles(string blobConnectionString, string adlsConnectionString, string blobContainerName, string blobFolderPath, string adlsContainerName, string adlsFolderPath, string adfCustName, string adfSourceSystem, string adfFeedName, string environment)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("DeleteBlobFiles method called.");

                string sourceToDestination = "B2R";
                string transactionStatusSuccess = "S";
                string transactionStatusFailure = "F";
                string transactionDescriptionSuccess = "File has been copied to Raw Data Layer of ADLS";
                string transactionDescriptionFailure = "File has not been copied to Raw Data Layer of ADLS";

                CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(blobConnectionString);
                CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

                Console.WriteLine("blobContainerName = " + blobContainerName);
                Console.WriteLine("blobFolderPath = " + blobFolderPath);
                // Ensure the container is exist.
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(blobContainerName))
                {
                    var blobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(blobContainerName);
                    blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();
                    CloudBlobDirectory cbd = blobContainer.GetDirectoryReference(blobFolderPath);
                }
             }
......
       }
```

This is the logging option which I would like to add in my custom activity or something doing essentially the same.
[image: Logging Checkbox for Predefined Copy Activity]

Answer (score 1):

I found the logs. The [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-custom-activity) say

> The stdout and stderr of your custom application are saved to the
> adfjobs container in the Azure Storage Linked Service you defined when
> creating Azure Batch Linked Service with a GUID of the task. You can
> get the detailed path from Activity Run output as shown in the
> following snippet

So I just checked which service account was associated with the Batch Account my custom activity was using and found the associated stdout and stderr files in the container **adfjobs**.